# Dropbox Url Images not showing on ImageView swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3

I fetch the image from services having dropbox url images and also use FLImageView third party to fetch the image data from server But Image with dropbox url not showing and other url images showing on ImageView .Please share suggestion thanks in advance.

Comment: Please share image url.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/jmzfk08mk8r0r1r/AAD-03urO7kgGcnp3gSJ1F-ba/bikano%20combos/BIKANO1042.jpg?raw=1

Comment: Please check URL that pass to image is same as this https://www.dropbox.com/sh/jmzfk08mk8r0r1r/AAD-03urO7kgGcnp3gSJ1F-ba/bikano%20combos/BIKANO1042.jpg?raw=1

Comment: Yes its correct . Its not the only url , image url data fetch through the services so , is directly use to the code using table view.

Comment: I tried same URL given by you and image load perfectly.

Comment: On Browser its loading But in App is not loading. Is there any credential or extra code require to use the dropbox image?

Comment: nop, I used it in app and there's no extra code to use dropbox url.

Comment: I don't know about FLImageView but I load image with sd_webImage.

Comment: @Kuldeep, Thanks for your suggestion . I try again by making some changes, might be it work

Comment: Okay, if it will not work that inform me.

Comment: Its work by using the untrimmed url of image .Can't able manage data like that.